# ESP32: gn.py: Could not find checkout in any parent of the current path. This must be run inside a checkout

Tags: linux, esp32, ninja, gn

complying an ESP32 project using the MATTER protocol from the github project: Connectedhomeip (https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/tree/master/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32)

im using ubuntu 20.02, tried using python 3.8  and 3.9 no difference to error.

i followed the following instructions from the above link, the instruction as pasted below

```
Building the Example Application

Building the example application requires the use of the Espressif ESP32 IoT Development Framework and the xtensa-esp32-elf toolchain for ESP32 modules or the riscv-esp32-elf toolchain for ESP32C3 modules.

The VSCode devcontainer has these components pre-installed, so you can skip this step. To install these components manually, follow these steps:

    Clone the Espressif ESP-IDF and checkout v4.4 release

      $ mkdir ${HOME}/tools
      $ cd ${HOME}/tools
      $ git clone https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git
      $ cd esp-idf
      $ git checkout v4.4
      $ git submodule update --init
      $ ./install.sh

    Install ninja-build

      $ sudo apt-get install ninja-build

Currently building in VSCode and deploying from native is not supported, so make sure the IDF_PATH has been exported(See the manual setup steps above).

    Setting up the environment

    $ cd ${HOME}/tools/esp-idf
    $ ./install.sh
    $ . ./export.sh
    $ cd {path-to-connectedhomeip}

    To download and install packages.

    $ source ./scripts/bootstrap.sh
    $ source ./scripts/activate.sh

    If packages are already installed then simply activate them.

    $ source ./scripts/activate.sh

    Target Set

To set IDF target, run set-target with one of the commands.

      $ idf.py set-target esp32
      $ idf.py set-target esp32c3

    Configuration Options

To build the default configuration (sdkconfig.defaults) skip to building the demo application.

To build a specific configuration (as an example m5stack):

      $ rm sdkconfig
      $ idf.py -D 'SDKCONFIG_DEFAULTS=sdkconfig_m5stack.defaults' build

Note: If using a specific device configuration, it is highly recommended to
start off with one of the defaults and customize on top of that. Certain
configurations have different constraints that are customized within the
device specific configuration (eg: main app stack size).

To customize the configuration, run menuconfig.

      $ idf.py menuconfig

Select ESP32 based Device Type through Demo->Device Type. The device types that are currently supported include ESP32-DevKitC (default), ESP32-WROVER-KIT_V4.1, M5Stack and ESP32C3-DevKitM.

    To build the demo application.

      $ idf.py build

    After building the application, to flash it outside of VSCode, connect your device via USB. Then run the following command to flash the demo application onto the device and then monitor its output. If necessary, replace /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART(MacOS) with the correct USB device name for your system(like /dev/ttyUSB0 on Linux). Note that sometimes you might have to press and hold the boot button on the device while it's trying to connect before flashing. For ESP32-DevKitC devices this is labeled in the functional description diagram.

      $ idf.py -p /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART flash monitor
```

When use >>idf.py to build the project i get the follow error

```
>>idf.py build
Executing action: all (aliases: build)
Running ninja in directory /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build
Executing "ninja all"...
ninja: warning: bad deps log signature or version; starting over
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
-- Found Python3: /home/csir/.espressif/python_env/idf5.0_py3.8_env/bin/python3.8 (found version "3.8.10") found components: Interpreter 
-- Project sdkconfig file /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/sdkconfig
Loading defaults file /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/sdkconfig.defaults...
-- App "chip-all-clusters-app" version: TE8/rc2-7-gf32685f35-dirty
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/esp_system/ld/memory.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/ld/esp32/sections.ld.in
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.api.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.libgcc.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-data.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.syscalls.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-funcs.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-time.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/ld/esp32.peripherals.ld
-- Components: QRCode app_trace app_update asio bootloader bootloader_support bt chip cmock coap console cxx driver efuse esp-tls esp32 esp32_mbedtls esp_adc_cal esp_common esp_eth esp_event esp_gdbstub esp_hid esp_http_client esp_http_server esp_https_ota esp_https_server esp_hw_support esp_lcd esp_local_ctrl esp_netif esp_phy esp_pm esp_ringbuf esp_rom esp_serial_slave_link esp_system esp_timer esp_websocket_client esp_wifi espcoredump esptool_py fatfs freemodbus freertos hal heap http_parser idf_test ieee802154 iperf json led_strip log lwip main mbedtls mdns mqtt newlib nvs_flash openssl openthread partition_table pcap perfmon pid_ctrl protobuf-c protocol_examples_common protocomm pthread qrcode screen-framework sdmmc soc spi_flash spidriver spiffs tcp_transport tcpip_adapter tft tinyusb ulp unity usb vfs wear_levelling wifi_provisioning wpa_supplicant xtensa
-- Component paths: /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/common/QRCode /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/app_trace /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/app_update /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/asio /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bt /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/components/chip /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/cmock /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/coap /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/console /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/cxx /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/driver /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp-tls /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32 /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/third_party/connectedhomeip/config/esp32/components/esp32_mbedtls /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_adc_cal /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_eth /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_event /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_gdbstub /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hid /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_http_client /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_http_server /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_https_ota /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_https_server /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_lcd /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_local_ctrl /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_netif /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_phy /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_pm /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_ringbuf /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_serial_slave_link /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_timer /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_websocket_client /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_wifi /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/espcoredump /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/fatfs /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/freemodbus /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/hal /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/heap /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/http_parser /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/idf_test /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/ieee802154 /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/examples/common_components/iperf /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/json /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/examples/common_components/led_strip /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/log /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/lwip /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/main /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/mbedtls /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/mdns /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/mqtt /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/nvs_flash /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/openssl /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/openthread /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/partition_table /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/examples/common_components/pcap /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/perfmon /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/examples/common_components/pid_ctrl /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/protobuf-c /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/examples/common_components/protocol_examples_common /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/protocomm /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/pthread /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/examples/common_components/qrcode /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/common/screen-framework /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/sdmmc /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/soc /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/spi_flash /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/common/m5stack-tft/repo/components/spidriver /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/spiffs /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/tcp_transport /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/tcpip_adapter /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/common/m5stack-tft/repo/components/tft /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/tinyusb /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/ulp /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/unity /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/usb /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/vfs /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/wear_levelling /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/wifi_provisioning /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/wpa_supplicant /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build
[7/1126] Generating ../../partition_table/partition-table.bin
Partition table binary generated. Contents:
*******************************************************************************
# ESP-IDF Partition Table
# Name, Type, SubType, Offset, Size, Flags
nvs,data,nvs,0x9000,24K,
otadata,data,ota,0xf000,8K,
phy_init,data,phy,0x11000,4K,
ota_0,app,ota_0,0x20000,1500K,
ota_1,app,ota_1,0x1a0000,1500K,
ot_storage,data,58,0x317000,8K,
*******************************************************************************
[261/1126] Performing configure step for 'bootloader'
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
-- Project sdkconfig file /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/sdkconfig
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/soc/esp32/ld/esp32.peripherals.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.api.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.libgcc.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom/esp32/ld/esp32.rom.newlib-funcs.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader/subproject/main/ld/esp32/bootloader.ld
-- Adding linker script /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader/subproject/main/ld/esp32/bootloader.rom.ld
-- Components: bootloader bootloader_support efuse esp32 esp_common esp_hw_support esp_rom esp_system esptool_py freertos hal log main micro-ecc newlib partition_table soc spi_flash xtensa
-- Component paths: /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader_support /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/efuse /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp32 /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_common /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_hw_support /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_rom /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/hal /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/log /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader/subproject/main /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/bootloader/subproject/components/micro-ecc /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/newlib /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/partition_table /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/soc /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/spi_flash /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/xtensa
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/bootloader
[270/1126] Performing build step for 'bootloader'
[1/1] cd /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/bootloader/esp-idf/esptool_py && /home/csir/.espressif/python_env/idf5.0_py3.8_env/bin/python /home/csir/esp/esp-idf/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 bootloader 0x1000 /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/bootloader/bootloader.bin
Bootloader binary size 0x6360 bytes. 0xca0 bytes (11%) free.
[585/1125] Performing configure step for 'chip_gn'
FAILED: esp-idf/chip/chip_gn-prefix/src/chip_gn-stamp/chip_gn-configure 
cd /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/chip && /home/csir/depot_tools/gn --root=/home/csir/connectedhomeip/config/esp32 gen --check --fail-on-unused-args /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/chip && /usr/bin/cmake -E touch /home/csir/connectedhomeip/examples/all-clusters-app/esp32/build/esp-idf/chip/chip_gn-prefix/src/chip_gn-stamp/chip_gn-configure
gn.py: Could not find checkout in any parent of the current path.
This must be run inside a checkout.
[586/1125] Building C object esp-idf/esp_serial_slave_link/CMakeFiles/__idf_esp_serial_slave_link.dir/essl_spi.c.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
ninja failed with exit code 1
```

I can see that the problem is in the file ~/depot_tools/gn.py
with the line 50:   bin_path = gclient_paths.GetBuildtoolsPlatformBinaryPath()

gclient_paths.GetBuildtoolsPlatformBinaryPath() returns "none"

what should the value be?

Comment: So did you read [BUILDING.md](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/blob/master/docs/guides/BUILDING.md) like the message says? This project requires GN.

Comment: yip i did, i believe GN is the problem, do you know how to reinstall it, when i run "gn" on the command line  i get this:                                                                                                                            
 pasted from terminal -> gn.py: Could not find checkout in any parent of the current path.
This must be run inside a checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Some hours ago I had exactly the same problem.

In my case, I didn't run `$ source ./scripts/bootstrap.sh` because I didn't worked, but I clone the whole git again in my home folder, lauched the command and (after almost an hour) run `idf.py set-target esp32` and `idf.py build` and it finally worked.

I followed more or less the following steps from this issue in Matter repo and it helped a lot:
https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/issues/15562#issuecomment-1057750597

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Hi yes i know this solution, lol because i was the one that posted it. this problem with 'gn' not found is still there for me on Ubuntu 20 LTS , did you follow these instructions on Ubuntu 18 or ubuntu 20?  

i need to get this working on ubuntu 20

Comment: I did on Ubuntu 20. Specifically on the WSL version